# Shiny - rintrojs on different tabset

Tags: r, shiny

I'm developing an interactive help in `Shiny` and obviously the choice was `rintrojs`.

When I look into the example and the doc I found a little ugly to add to every element we want the interactive help the `introBox` command ( https://github.com/carlganz/rintrojs see example here)

So I searched for a better solution and i came up with this app who won the 1st shiny contest https://kevinrue.shinyapps.io/isee-shiny-contest/# ( By the way, I'm stunned by what the app can do, kudos to the creators) . Anyway their approach to the interactive help was to write a text file let's call `tour_1` like this:

```
#Welcome;Welcome to the interactive tour
#allpanels;iSEE provides a Shiny interface that allows you to generate a series of panels for exploring 
#redDimPlot1;For example,....
```

where the first element is something like the div css element and second element is the text for the help.

With this `observeEvent` function inside server.R

```
  observeEvent(input$tour, {

      tour <- read.delim(file.path(getwd(),"help", "tour_1"),
                         sep=";", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, row.names=NULL, quote="")

      introjs(session, options=list(steps=tour))
  })
```

the interactive help is started when user click the `tour` button.

Everything is fine and neat. The problem is that the app `Isee` I refered to, has all element in one page while my app is distributed across different tabset.
I'd like to have an interactive help for an element which is not in the first page.

Somehow i should adapt the first element of the tour_1 file to refer to the correct tabset and element inside it.

I've tried something like `tabelmentid-elementofthattabid` but it doesn't work...

Comment: Are you looking for a single walkthrough button that will move a user from tab to tab or multiple walkthough buttons, 1 on each tab, that will just talk about the content on the current tab?

Comment: a single walkthrough. No matter what part of the app user is visiting, he can click on an help button and take a tour of the app. The tour should bring him from the first page to the last one explaining every component inside that page.